# Labels for multiple instances of the same button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

I am wondering how to go about creating multiple of the 'same' `input type`in html. I have a grid, and would like some option for each row. I would like to apply a `label` to each `input type`, but I am running into the issue of how to reference each `input type` in the `label`'s `for` attribute. Since `for` uses an `id`, and I have multiple instances of the same `input type`, how would I go about reference the `input type` without doing something unfavorable such as `id='button0'`, `id='button1'`, `id='button2'` and so on?

For example (code stripped down for simplicity, and I am using `kendo-ui` styling),

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <p>This is a column</p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox" id="select-this">
        <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="select-this">Select this</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <p>This is another column</p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox" id="select-this">
        <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="select-this">Select this</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Having two elements with the same `id` (in this case `id="select-this"`) is ill-advised, and `for` does not seem able to reference a `class`. Is there a better way to do this using some tool such as jQuery or is there a work-around?

Comment: `id` should be unique. So just set a unique `id` and make it work :-)

Comment: @Lain imagine a case with 100 checkboxes. Is there really no better way to generate these input elements than `id='checkbox0'`, `id='checkbox1'` ... `id='checkbox99'` ?

Comment: I see what you mean.

Comment: Have you looked at templating the items at all? If you are using kendo's grids etc. then their templating is fairly easy to get along with. I have prepared a simple dojo http://dojo.telerik.com/ocAVAWIr which will dynamically id the items for you

Comment: @DavidShorthose, that was very useful, thank you for that demo! I will look more into templating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a script that sets all `id` dynamically and set those new `id` as labels `for` attribute.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  for(let tL=document.querySelectorAll('.k-checkbox'), i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; i++){
    var tLabel = tL[i].parentNode.querySelector('label.k-checkbox-label');
    if(tLabel){
      tL[i].name = tL[i].id = 'whatever' + i;
      tLabel.setAttribute('for', tL[i].id)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <p>This is a column</p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox">
        <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="select-this">Select this</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <p>This is another column</p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox">
        <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="select-this">Select this</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Given the OP mentions cases with 100+ checkboxes, one would *hope* that his html code is dynamically generated, and so it would probably make more sense to already set the unique ids at generation time, and not after the fact through DOM manipulations.

Comment: @Kevin Van Dyck: Well we can only speculate on that. Yet to be honest, I would go with John R suggestion, since the `id` wont matter at all - however the DOM gets generated.

Comment: depending on how the value of the checkbox is processed afterwards, you might still need a unique `name` attribute for your elements, so you might as well use that as the `id` as well...

Comment: @Lain No need for speculation, here it is straight from the horse's mouth: I mentioned the case with 100+ checkboxes because that is what I will be working with. I now realized I should have mentioned that in the post.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion for you is, you can use `input` inside `label` as like below example.

**Example:**

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <p>This is a column</p>
    <label class="k-checkbox-label"><input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox">Select this</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <p>This is another column</p>
    <label class="k-checkbox-label"><input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox">Select this</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Totally forgot about that possibility :-)

Comment: Sadly, this syntax does not seem to work with `kendo`. See: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xsqp1a53/5/)

Comment: @Kelly Freet: It seems to be a styling/event bubbling issue - the value gets properly set in the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <p>This is a column</p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox" id="select-this-one">
        <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="select-this-one">Select this</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <p>This is another column</p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox" id="select-this-two">
        <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="select-this-two">Select this</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

`Id` name can't be duplicated. `id` is a unique property. But you can have multiple `class` with same name.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have multiple `input`s with the same `type` attribute, that does not mean that they should have the same `id`. All `input`s should have unique `id`s.

> … how would I go about referencing the input type without doing something unfavorable such as `id='button0'`, `id='button1'`, `id='button2'` and so on?

Unique `id`s are not unfavorable in general. The unfavorable part of your example is the arbitrariness of your `id` values. Usually it is possible to give each `id` a meaningful name, like `id="confirm-button"`, `id="cancel-button"`, `id="more-information"`. And if there are multiple rows, each with confirm buttons, then usually there is a unique name or number for each row that can be added to make each row unique – for example, `id="confirm-button-product-583"` and `id="confirm-button-product-112"`.

So for your example, some meaningful IDs might be `select-left-col` and `select-right-col`:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <p>This is a column</p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox" id="select-left-col">
        <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="select-left-col">Select this</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <p>This is another column</p>
        <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox" id="select-right-col">
        <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="select-right-col">Select this</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could name the `id`s more specifically if you know what each column represents, such as `select-existing-setting` and `select-new-setting`.

Answer (score 0):

> `for` does not seem able to reference a `class`

Clicking a `label` with a `for` attribute will put the focus on the element with the corresponding `id`, so which behavior would you expect when two elements have the same `id` or `class`?

Either you use unique `id`s on your elements (as you should), or you don't use the `for` attribute on your `label`s, because it makes absolutely no sense to have a non-unique `for` attribute.